# Fully qualified class name while using exceptionSuper argument in CXF Wsdl2Java utilty

Tags: cxf, wsdl2java

This is related to this question and the subsequent patch applied to cxf .

[When using a WSDL-first approach to generate java stubs, is there a way to make exceptions extend RuntimeException instead of Exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192477/when-using-a-wsdl-first-approach-to-generate-java-stubs-is-there-a-way-to-make/15396274#15396274)

Thanks Daniel and Piepera for the patch . But the generated code only adds the classname instead of fully qualified name and there is no import statement added for the custom exception supplied.

I have specified to use "com.google.adwords.api.AdwordsException" as exceptionSuper and wsdl2java maven plugin creates the following wsdl fault . But it didn't add an import statement for com.google.adwords.api.AdwordsException and compilation failed.

```
 @WebFault(name = "ApiExceptionFault", targetNamespace = "https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/billing/v201209")
  public class ApiException extends AdwordsException {
```

Could you please fix it to either add the import statement or use the fully qualified name.

---

**WSDL2JAVA Usage**

wsdl2java -d C:\Dev\src\main\java  -exceptionSuper com.google.adwords.api.AdwordsException -client -verbose -xjc-Xvalue-constructor -xjc-npa  https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201209/CampaignService?wsdl